# 現在のコンテキストに存在しませんと表示される

Tags: c#

最近C#の勉強を始めたのですが参考書に書いてある以下のコードをvs2017で実行すると
`現在のコンテキストに"Console"という名前は存在しません` と表示されてしまいます。
なぜでしょうか？

```
using System;

class Sumple1
{
 public static void Main()
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");` とした場合はどのような出力になるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

プロジェクトを作成する際に **Console App (.NET Framework)** を選択してください。

> `現在のコンテキストに"Console"という名前は存在しません`と表示されてしまいます。なぜでしょうか？

UWP等、コンソールが存在しないプロジェクトタイプを選択してしまったものと推測されます。